# How can I create a differentiable function to cap at 100?

Tags: piecewise-continuity

How can implement a function similar to
$ \ln \bigl( \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \bigl) $

[image]

It should be below piecewise function and should be differentiable

f(n) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x$ < 100} \\
\to 100, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

I need this function to implement a differentiable activation function in pytorch. I tried functions like below, which didn't help

[image: my shot at fn]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts

Comment: formatted with MathJax

Comment: I'm sure you can to this with a bump function.  See the example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Concrete_example   My brain seems to have stopped for the night, I'm sorry to say.